# Is there a way to export coodinates from a feature class which has no X/Y column?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinates

I have shape feature class of a province in France. The Geometry type is polygon.

The feature class has columns which describe elevation, landuse, slope and so on. But it does not contain X and Y columns to describe to coordinates. 
I want to do a climate analysis for this province and already have the simulation files of the climate models. These files contain XY coordinates of rasters within this french province. But I can not visualize the possible climate change because my feature class has no XY coordinates.

I am not very well versed in using ArcGIS, so I don't know how I can add coordinates into my feature class now. The only thing I know is that I can't add them manually because the feature class has about 20000 IDs. For very ID, coordinates are missing.
Is there a way to get the coordinates from the existing feature class?

Comment: Hey Carl - Are you looking to write each polygon's CENTROID coordinates to your feature class? The reason I ask is because a polygon will contain an array of many X/Y coordinates, making up its vertices, giving it shape. If so, you can add a field to the attribute table for your feature class and run the [calculate geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000) command.

Comment: Hi Jim! THanks for your answer! Yes, I would like to know the coordinates of the CENTROID of each polygon.

Comment: Ok no problem. In this case you would add two fields with type 'DOUBLE' to your feature class, one called "CENTROID_X", and another called "CENTROID_Y". Then, run the [calculate geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000) command on each field, selecting "X Coordinate of Centroid" and "Y Coordinate of Centroid" respectively.

Comment: Thank you Jim. I did it how you wrote and I have two coordinate columns now :-) Tomorrow I will try if my program can write the simulated temperatures to the correct coordinates :-)
Another question: At the moment I cant display anything of my feature class. It means that I use Symbology to display for example elevation with my favorite colour-ramp, but after applying it does not change anything in the data view. The map only keeps grey and the elevation is not shown. I never had such a problem. Is something about my feature class corrupt?

Another

Answer (score 1):

ArcMap has this functionality available in a few easy steps, as described [here](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32988).

In the attributes table, add your X and Y fields to your feature class.

Right-click on each field and select `Calculate Geometry`.

Select `X Coordinate of Centroid` or `Y Coordinate of Centroid` as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

apart from creating your own X Y columns as mentioned by @Emil Brundage, you can also use the built in tool called "[Export Feature attributes to ascii](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005p0000003v000000)".

This is the answer for your title question, but what you need seems to be different. If you have a raster that you want to compare with your features, I suggest that you use "extract multivalue to point" (for point feature) or "zonal statistics" (for polygon features) in order to put the datasets in a comparable way.